# The tab key is not working correctly when indenting a list in the GitHub Issue editor

Tags: list, github, tabs, markdown

The tab key is not working correctly when indenting a list in the GitHub Issue editor.

I hope the tab key in GitHub Issues works as efficiently as it does in regular markdown editors.